# Flutter- drag down to dismiss

Tags: flutter

I'd like to dismiss page with drag down like this.
But I don't know whether use `gesture` or `draggable` either way I have no idea how to show previous page as you drag down.
Anyone know how to do?

[image] .

**Edit**

I ended it up like this.
I'm not sure if this is the best way but at least it works fine for me.
Hope it helps someone:)

```
return Dismissible(
  key: Key('some key here'),
  direction: DismissDirection.down,
  onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.pop(context),
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Image.network(
        'URL',
        fit:BoxFit.cover
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: i am also looking for similar thing .. have you found any solution ? @TwoSan

Comment: I ended up using Dismissible.

Comment: it works if you don't have any scrollable in the container .. Dismissible doesnt work if there is any ListView or Scrollable .. I haven't found any solution to this. Let us know if you have.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about that :(

Comment: @TwoSan can you provide us the code you used in the end?

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren Sorry for  late response.  I edited my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Dismissible` widget for this. Docs with example: https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible

Answer (score 32):

A simple example of drag up/down to dismiss a page using `Dismissible`:

```dart
Dismissible(
    direction: DismissDirection.vertical,
    key: const Key('key'),
    onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
    child: ...
)
```

Comment: Can we set this as only bottom to top dismissible? So that user can't be able to dismiss by dragging top to bottom, (I have top sheet rather than bottom sheet, it looks odd when you scroll it top to bottom)

Comment: @EmreAkcan have you tried using direction: DismissDirection.up,

Answer (score 13):

### I was solving same issue for myself

[image]

This is the dartpad [link](https://dartpad.dev/ecb28c29c646b7f38139b1e7f44129b7) for demo above

### Full source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            showGeneralDialog(
              barrierLabel: "Label",
              barrierDismissible: false,
              barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
              transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
              context: context,
              pageBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2) {
                return SecondRoute();
              },
              transitionBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2, child) {
                return SlideTransition(
                  position: Tween(begin: Offset(0, 1), end: Offset(0, 0))
                      .animate(anim1),
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      direction: DismissDirection.vertical,
      key: const Key('key'),
      onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Second Route"),
        ),
        body: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            child: SizedBox.expand(child: FlutterLogo()),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, left: 12, right: 12),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### *NOTE: not tested for cases when `SecondRoute` has (`ListView` or `SingleChildScroll`) but I think in that case if you drag starting from AppBar or from location not covered by ListView it should dismiss as expected*